# Invalid session when trying to create a session in OKTA

Tags: okta, okta-api

Very new to okta flow, please bear with my ignorance.

I am doing a poc to access sharepoint from my external site and sharepoint is authenticated through OKTA. I want to start getting list view data from share point and expose it on my site.

**1) What is the difference of authenticating using username / password flow (vs) using token to authenticate into OKTA?**

**Step 1: Auth in through username / password get the session token**
[image]

**Step 2 : After this I tried to create a session as per docs:**

http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/sessions.html#create-session-with-session-token

[image]

Comment: Please show some love on this question guys :(, struck big time

Comment: Hi Rao, what is the JSON response you get when you use the Primary Authentication method from the /api/v1/authn endpoint? Do you get a sessionToken value? If so, you must exchange this sessionToken for a session quickly enough that your token does get invalidated. So if you use Postman, for instance, try to have 2 tabs open, one with Authentication/Primary Authentication and the other one with Sessions/Create Session with Session Token. Once you get a SUCCESS response from the Primary Authentication tab, copy the sessionToken value quickly and paste it into the Create Session request body.

Comment: And let me know how it goes!

Comment: You also need to make sure that you have a valid apiKey that you pass to our API when you call the /api/v1/sessions endpoint. You must do by adding an Authorization request header that starts with SSWS and then has your Okta API key. This header is already available in our Postman's Sessions collection so you only need to add it in other tools you might use. If you do use Postman and it still doesn't work, you should make sure you have a valid apiKey, which you can test by calling the List Users method in the Users collection. Let me know if that fixes your issue!

Comment: Raphael thanks for you inputs i finally managed to auth in get the session token, pass it and get the cookie token. Thanks for the help :), trying to figure out how i would use this cookie and tie up to the redirecturl and get data from the app connected to okta

Comment: Rao, could you please tell me what helped you in my comments above? I would like to leave a real answer to that discussion (and hope you'll +1 it :) ).

Comment: As far as automating the authentication on SharePoint through Okta, I would suggest the following:

1. Grab the App Embed Link from the General settings of your SharePoint On Prem app (in Okta)
2. Add ?onetimetoken=[your_okta_session_token] (so note you don't need to call the /api/v1/sessions endpoint in your case) and create a Get HttpRequest from your code. 
3. You will retrieve a SAML response which you most likely need to parse and then call SharePoint to get the SharePoint cookie you need. I'm not quite sure how to do the rest

Comment: but hopefully [this SO  discussion](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110870/how-to-use-saml-token-to-authenticate-sharepont-2013-online) may help (look at Wictor Wilen's code sample referenced at the bottom of the discussion)

Comment: @RaphaelLondner I was missing the part that I need a API token, I assumed the username password flow would pass me the token, later in your notes I saw that the username pass flow is deprecated. I relooked at the docs and the API test client page was super helpful ( kudos to the team that documented the postman API test page). Please post that I need both API token and session token to auth in comment, I will accept it as an answer

Comment: Thank you for the response and I've passed on your positive feedback on the Postman API to the doc author.
You're correct that the username/password flow with the /api/v1/sessions endpoint is deprecated and you should now use the /api/v1/authn endpoint from now on. Thanks again for the feedback and good luck with the rest of your effort with SharePoint authentication.

Comment: @Raphael i was able to load the sessions collections on postman test client and still get the cookie token with username password flow. I will paste a screenshot if needed, the collections says deprecated still i can get the cookie token just an FYI to look at

Comment: you are correct. "Deprecated" does not mean it no longer works in some scenarios (such as yours). As mentioned in [Create Session with Session Token](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/sessions.html#create-session-with-session-token, the username/password payload is marked deprecated because it does not support the whole authentication flow. Specifically, if a user has to go through a second-factor validation, this method will fail to create a valid session. Using the /authn API first will go you through the MFA process and then let you create a session with the /sessions API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing a valid Okta API token (cf. [Getting a Token](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/getting_a_token.html) ) when calling the /api/v1/sessions endpoint. In any event, you should use the /api/v1/authn endpoint for authentication purposes and that one usually doesn't need an api token (unless you want to authenticate it from a trusted application).

The /api/v1/sessions API with the username/password payload is deprecated so you should shy away from using it in favor of the /api/v1/authn API.

I hope this helps!